# Center the navi bar items while keeping the background color full-width

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and working on a navi bar for my page but I can't center all the items of the bar while keeping the bar full-width. Did I miss something?

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
   }
   
   .naviMenu ul li {
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 16px;
   }
   
   .naviMenu ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
   }
   
   .naviMenu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #111;
   }
```

```html
<div class="naviMenu">
    <ul>
     <li><div id="homePage">Home</div></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li>Text</li>
     <li><a href="photo.html">Photo</li>
     <li><a href="special.html">Special Project</li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</li>
    </ul>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: As per your give screenshot add body{margin:0;padding:0}

Comment: Or add *{margin:0;padding:0}

Comment: Thank you, vedankita. It becomes full-width but the items are still left-aligned rather than centered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is a bit broken with missing closing tags and divs instead of links. But what you're doing is fairly straight forward - you just need to tweak things a bit.
Mark up:

```
<div class="naviMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The main problem is the float left you have on the li element currently.
CSS:

```
.naviMenu ul {
  width: 100%; /* make it full width */
  background: #333;
  text-align: center; /* align it center */
  list-style: none;
}
.naviMenu ul li {
  display: inline-block; /* inline-block respects align center. allows padding */
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}
.naviMenu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygLZXK

Comment: Thank you, Bat. But when I copied and paste the code you gave me and what I had is like https://s24.postimg.org/cn9jr6tt1/problem.png/ . Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @GaryHu check your markup - this is likely to do with the divs instead of links.

Comment: @GaryHu - no worries! If it helped, feel free to mark it as the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.naviMenu ul li {
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.naviMenu ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.naviMenu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="naviMenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="homePage">Home</div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li><a href="photo.html">Photo</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="special.html">Special Project</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```